# Optimising cargo build times in Docker

Tags: docker, dependencies, rust, rust-cargo

I am developing an API with Rust, and am managing the environments, including the external database with Docker. Every time I make a change to the API code, cargo rebuilds, and since Docker doesn't cache anything to do with the `ADD` statement to copy the Rust directory over to the container, it re-downloads all the packages, which is a fairly lengthy process since I'm using Nickel, which seems to have a boatload of dependencies.

Is there a way to bring those dependencies in prior to running `cargo build`? At least that way if the dependencies change it will only install what's required, similar to Cargo compiling locally.

Here's the Dockerfile I currently use:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl build-essential ca-certificates file xutils-dev nmap -y
RUN mkdir /rust
WORKDIR /rust
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -s >> rustup.sh
RUN chmod 755 /rust/rustup.sh
RUN ./rustup.sh -y
ENV PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH SSL_VERSION=1.0.2h
RUN rustup default 1.11.0
RUN curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$SSL_VERSION.tar.gz -O && \
    tar -xzf openssl-$SSL_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    cd openssl-$SSL_VERSION && ./config && make depend && make install && \
    cd .. && rm -rf openssl-$SSL_VERSION*
ENV OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/ssl/lib \
    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/ssl/include \
    OPENSSL_STATIC=1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN cargo build
EXPOSE 20000
CMD ./target/debug/api
```

And here's my Cargo.toml

```
[profile.dev]
debug = true

[package]
name = "api"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["Vignesh Sankaran <developer@ferndrop.com>"]

[dependencies]
nickel = "= 0.8.1"
mongodb = "= 0.1.6"
bson = "= 0.3.0"
uuid = { version = "= 0.3.1", features = ["v4"] }
```

Comment: Maybe you can add and compile a dummy application with the same dependencies first.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1891. Also note that you can install the correct toolchain in one step `./rustup.sh -y --default-toolchain 1.11.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Docker does cache the layer built from the `ADD` (preferably `COPY`) instruction, provided the sources haven't changed. You could make use of that and get your dependencies cached by copying the `Cargo.toml` in first, and doing a build.

But unfortunately you need something to build, so you could do it with a single source file and a dummy `lib` target in your manifest:

```
[lib]
name = "dummy"
path = "dummy.rs"
```

In your Dockerfile build the dummy separately:

```
COPY Cargo.toml /app/Cargo.toml
COPY dummy.rs /app/dummy.rs
RUN cargo build --lib
```

The output of this layer will be cached, with all the dependencies installed, and then you can go on to add the rest of your code (in the same `Dockerfile`):

```
COPY /src/ app/src/
RUN cargo build
```

The `dummy` stuff is ugly, but it means your normal build will be quick, as it comes from the cached layer, and when you change dependencies in your `Cargo.toml` then Docker will pick it up and build a new layer with updated dependencies.

Comment: *copying the `Cargo.toml` in first* — **and** the `Cargo.lock`!

Comment: I've successfully used this technique with Ruby projects, copying in the `Gemfile` / `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install`.

Comment: Why `COPY` and not `ADD`?

Comment: `COPY` just copies the file/directory from the context into the image layer. `ADD` does that too, but it can also use a Web address as the source, and if the source is a compressed file it will unzip it on the image. That functionality isn't always expected, so unless you know you need it, it you're better off with `COPY`.

Answer (score 4):

This question is a year and a half old at this point. Still, no `cargo build --deps-only` option, but I thought I'd share my solution, which is reasonably lightweight. You don't have to modify any of your host files to do it:

```
COPY Cargo.toml .
RUN mkdir src \
    && echo "// dummy file" > src/lib.rs \
    && cargo build
```

This will build the dependencies and cache them. Later when you copy in the actual source files (or in my case, use `--volumes`), it will overwrite the dummy file, so the dummy file is totally temporary. You could also explicitly `rm` it after the build if you needed to.

Comment: Is there an issue in cargo about a `--deps-only` flag?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a dummy file, you can also let the build fail:

```
RUN cargo build || true
COPY ...
RUN cargo build
```

Don't forget to add `--release` to both places if you want optimized builds.

Comment: I still need to copy `cargo.lock` and `cargo.toml`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of digging into this, and it seems the best solution is to do it in multiple stages.  The longest one is the initial index download. Also note that the dependencies pre-build step makes the `target/` less predictable, so  for cleaner results it might make sense to remove it.  It should work fine for the development/incremental builds though.

P.S. I did it with alpine, but it will work the same way for any other Rust bases - just change the system packages step to another package manager like `apt`.

```
FROM rust:alpine
ARG RUST_APP_NAME=myapp
WORKDIR /rust_app

# Each of these steps may take a long time, so do them separately to take advantage of Docker caching.
# The order of the steps is important as they are ordered by the likelihood of change.
#
# Downloading the crates.io index. This might be the slowest of the steps.
# Note that we must have at least one dependency in Cargo.toml for fetch to work.
RUN cargo init && \
    cargo add serde && \
    cargo fetch && \
    rm -rf *

# Install system packages
RUN apk add --no-cache musl-dev

# Download just the dependencies listed in the Cargo.toml
COPY Cargo.toml /rust_app/
COPY Cargo.lock /rust_app/
RUN mkdir -p src && \
    echo 'fn main() { eprintln!("The build broke!"); std::process::exit(1); }' > src/main.rs && \
    cargo fetch && \
    rm -rf src

# Compile just the dependencies listed in the Cargo.toml
# Note that this step will create some intermediate files in the target/ directory.
# Cargo will rebuild the final binary/lib in the next step, but for cleaner build
# you may want to remove this step and let it recompile all dependencies on each docker build.
RUN mkdir -p src && \
    echo 'fn main() { eprintln!("The build broke!"); std::process::exit(1); }' > src/main.rs && \
    cargo build --release && \
    rm -rf src && \
    rm -rf target/release/deps/${RUST_APP_NAME}-* && \
    rm -rf target/release/deps/lib${RUST_APP_NAME}-* && \
    rm -rf target/release/.fingerprint/${RUST_APP_NAME}-* && \
    rm -rf target/release/.fingerprint/lib${RUST_APP_NAME}-* && \
    rm -rf target/release/incremental/${RUST_APP_NAME}-* && \
    rm -rf target/release/incremental/lib${RUST_APP_NAME}-* && \
    rm -rf target/release/${RUST_APP_NAME}* && \
    rm -rf target/release/lib${RUST_APP_NAME}*

# Copy the source code and build the target
ADD . .
RUN cargo build --release
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-running a `Dockerfile` for an incremental build seems to me like an **anti-pattern**. However, you are not alone and the caching ability seems useful for multi-stage or docker-in-docker builds.

- [Optimizing builds with cache](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/)
- [`RUN --mount=type=cache`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache)
- [`ADD --link`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy---link)
- [Keep layers small](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/#keep-layers-small)

*I suggest to rethink your approach to containerization for build systems.*

#### Docker Image

A `Dockerfile` is used to create an image. The flexibility that is allowed is awesome but can lead to some confusion. An image should be the default environment will all the dependencies and tools loaded. It is a template from which containers are spawned. Even the word `image` implies that a captured environment is **unmoving**. When you take a picture of a family event you are capturing *a moment in time*, that you can't go back and change. Well, I guess you could use photoshop... but you get the point :). Obviously, in `docker` world images change all the time but the meaning remains.

- `RUN ./rustup.sh -y` this is good you are setting up the rust toolchain
- `RUN cargo build` Do you want a code build to be **baked into the image?**

Also the confusion is further exacerbated by *services*. If your image's only purpose is to set up the environment and start a service then `RUN ./my_service` is perfect for this. Because any container spawned from this image has the purpose of starting the service.

I do want to mention "build context." I have been bitten by this as well. When you `docker build -t my_image .` pay attention to the **`.`** This means that the current directory will be available to Docker when building the image. This can slow `docker build` times dramatically as it has to copy recursively everything over to the docker daemon. I think a better practice (for large projects) is to:

1. Use the explicit flag `-f Dockerfile` that way you can use a different context folder
2. Use [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-dockerignore-file)
3. Be explicit with the `PATH` for build context, remember this could be a `URL` or a [tarball!](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tarball-contexts)

#### Docker Containers

A `container` is as temporary/permanent as you need. Meaning if you are doing incremental builds then have a container persist through the builds to retain the cache. You can create a container and "detach" it to keep it running in the background. This way you can `docker exec` any command you want in the running container. Environment is a loaded term that changes definitions based on your context. Try to separate the image from the container. In other words, try to separate the development tools (libs, bins, etc.) from the incremental build cache.

Running containers can be:

1. Detached and kept in the background
2. Reattached, jump in with a shell
3. committed, save current state *into an new image*!
4. [Created in all sorts of ways](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_create/)

> NOTE: You can *detach* from a running container with the chord <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>

##### Deeper Dive

If you feel like putting on some scuba gear and taking a deeper dive, I highly suggest [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). After a while, the command line arguments become very numerous, so thankfully Docker created `compose` which is a declarative versatile approach (YAML file) to cli arguments.

I love tools that are flexible to your needs and at the same time I love languages like Rust that are very strict and prevent errors. The joys of software development...

Answer (score -2):

You can create an intermediate image and build your final image from it.
Eg:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl build-essential ca-certificates file xutils-dev nmap -y
RUN mkdir /rust
...
```

build using `docker build -t mybaseimage .`

```
FROM mybaseimage
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN cargo build
EXPOSE 20000
CMD ./target/debug/api
```

`docker build -t finalimage .`

That way only the mybaseimage is rebuilt