# Is it possible to install Cargo dependencies in the same directory as my project?

Tags: dependencies, rust, rust-cargo

I'm running my Rust project with Docker. It is fast, but there is a problem when I add an external dependency. Since Docker starts a new every time I run the "cargo run" command, it then fetches the external dependencies from the Internet again.

While this is related to an issue I have with Docker, I don't believe this is restricted to Docker as it can be an issue for a broad range of setups. What I'm looking for is simple regardless of Docker or anything else: Install the dependencies in the Rust project folder instead of having it installed globally, like in Node package manager.

Comment: I'm by no means a Docker expert, but wouldn't it be easier and more idiomatic to maintain a cache outside of the container and mount it? The crates downloaded by cargo end up somewhere in `~/.cargo/registry`. You could mount an external cache to `~/.cargo` or something like that to cache the downloads.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm talking about the Docker build. I'm running the cargo build after the Docker build.

Comment: Needed to know the same thing, to have `cargo fetch` all dependencies into the repo, as to start a review/audit of the codebase, therefore happy to have found this question already asked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dependencies are already *built* inside every project; in the `target` directory. The dependencies source code is cached in your user directory at `$HOME/.cargo`.

If you wish to *not use* the user-wide download cache, you can specify the `CARGO_HOME` environment variable and have a separate cache:

```
CARGO_HOME=$PWD/cargo cargo build
```

---

As you drew the analogy to npm, note that Cargo's solution is basically what yarn does — a global cache of downloads and the project's specific dependencies are built / linked into the `node_modules` directory.

Comment: I'm getting a weird error "warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [2/-1] failed to mmap. Could not write data: Invalid argument" I'm not sure if it is related to Docker?

Comment: @OmarAbid yes. If you put the error message into Google, the first result for me has [a comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2808#issuecomment-279698324) about how this doesn't work on Docker on macOS. The good news is that the question and answer, as you requested, is unrelated to Docker. ^_^

Comment: yes I was just reading into it. I marked this as an answer. Sorry for the trouble :/

Comment: @OmarAbid haha, don't mind me, I'm just grumpy! Were I in your shoes, I'd follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661138, build the container with all the dependencies, then layer on my local code and build.

Comment: this means that I have to "re-build" every time I add a dependency. Good thing docker saves the previous steps, so it won't take that long. But I guess I don't have much of choice now with this bug.